# Regex required for following string

Tags: python, regex

`search?query=EasterGmPromo2020&searchType=mktgattribute&monet=CURATED&fulfillment=all`
I have such type of strings. I wanted to get data from ?query=EasterGmPromo2020 only. How to do in regex.

Comment: Use `urllib.parse` instead of regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a query string. There are many packages out there that parse URLs, no need for regex here.

One way is to use `urllib.parse` (built into Python 3)

```
from urllib import parse

params = parse.parse_qs("query=EasterGmPromo2020&searchType=mktgattribute&monet=CURATED&fulfillment=all")
print(params["query"])
```